# Debug node SSL handshake

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate

I have a node js server described as this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');

const log = require('./lib/log');

const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server.crt')),
  ca: [fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ca.pem'))],
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true
}, function() { log.debug('ok'); });

server.listen(8080, () => log.info(`Server listening on port 8080`));
```

My issue is that the certificate presented by the client gets rejected while it has been signed by this CA.

I've tried to use OpenSSL to be sure:

```
$ openssl s_server -key server.key -cert server.crt -accept 8080 -www -CAfile ca.pem -verify 5
verify depth is 5
depth=0 C = FR, O = MyO, OU = MyOU, CN = MyCN
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, O = MyO, OU = MyOU, CN = MyCN
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

Is there a way to have a verbose mode or to get the client's certificate?